# How to sum up the results of a MySQL query using UNION

Tags: mysql, database

For a leaderboard with earned commission of sales agents for my company I use data from two different tables. I use the following query to calculate the earned commission per agent.

```
SELECT agent, SUM(p.vergoeding_partner) as sum FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Proposities p ON s.product_name = p.naam
WHERE finalized_at > CURDATE() AND flow=165
GROUP BY agent
UNION
SELECT agent, SUM(IF(eancode_e<>'' AND eancode_g<>'',p.vergoeding_partner*2, p.vergoeding_partner)) as sum FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Proposities p ON t.productnaam = p.naam
WHERE finalized_datetime > CURDATE()
GROUP BY agent
ORDER by sum DESC;
```

This query results in a table where there are two rows for each agent. One row with the sum of first part of the query per agent (Sales table) and one row with the sum of the second part of the query per agent (Transactions table). Now I am looking for to query the sum of those values per agent.

So lets say I have this result:

```
+-------+------+
| agent | sum  |
+-------+------+
| Paul  | 1000 |
+-------+------+
| Paul  | 800  |
+-------+------+
| John  | 400  |
+-------+------+
| John  | 200  |
+-------+------+
```

And I want to have this as a result of the query:

```
+-------+------+
| agent | sum  |
+-------+------+
| Paul  | 1800 |
+-------+------+
| John  | 600  |
+-------+------+
```

Is this possible? If yes: How!

Comment: Use your query as subquery, summarize in outer query.

Comment: @Akina How can I do this. I don't even have a clue how to start on such a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT agent, SUM(`sum`) AS sum
FROM ( SELECT agent, SUM(p.vergoeding_partner) as sum 
       FROM Sales s
       INNER JOIN Proposities p ON s.product_name = p.naam
       WHERE finalized_at > CURDATE() AND flow=165
       GROUP BY agent
     UNION
       SELECT agent, SUM(IF(eancode_e<>'' AND eancode_g<>'',p.vergoeding_partner*2, p.vergoeding_partner)) as sum 
       FROM Transactions t
       INNER JOIN Proposities p ON t.productnaam = p.naam
       WHERE finalized_datetime > CURDATE()
       GROUP BY agent
     ) total
GROUP BY agent
```